# want to make fields readonly if the record is saved , openerp

Tags: crm, odoo, erp

I want to make some fields (`checkboxes`) readonly if the record is saved. the next assigned person can change in some fields. But some fields must be restricted that no body can change them. One way is to do so is to put user or group rights. But I want it in another way. Any way there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This condition is work perfectly

`<field name="freezing_on_all_channels" attrs="{'readonly':[('id','!=', False)]}"/>`

or `attrs="{'readonly':[('id','!=',0)]}"` (note: the 0 not in quotes '0'),

you just made one mistake; if you put 
   `<"field name="id" invisible="1"/>` in the view as well, then it will work as expected.

Thanks

Comment: its solved my issue , but what did you say in the last sentence , i could not understand it. You have to put "field name="id" invisble="1"/>" in the view also?. I only remove quote and its working.

Comment: this solution works nicely in all cases, unlike the "state" test which only works for objects with a state (eg res.partner doesn't have a state)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible when state is change.

You can do it by writing "attrs={}" attribute in your .xml.

For example:

> < field name="your_field" attrs="{'readonly':[('state','=','saved')]}"/>

Hope this will solve your problem.

Thank You...

Comment: seems very good solution. I tried it, but its not working. Why I dont know.

Comment: I tried another solution , that is  <field name="freezing_on_all_channels" attrs="{'readonly':[('id','!=','0')]}"/>. It worked, I dont know its better to use or not. Please guide?

Comment: the above solution <field name="freezing_on_all_channels" attrs="{'readonly':[('id','!=','0')]}"/> did not work also. I think '!=' is not working. Kindly guide me?

Comment: This will not work unless there is a state 'save'. Also, if there are other states, the field will be editable again after state chage.

Comment: Its just an example about how to make your field read-only based on condition.

Answer (score 0):

try with below

```
'your_field': fields.char('Name', type='char',store=True,readonly=True),
```